# Integration of an equation

Tags: integration

Can this differential equation be converted from
$\frac{dv}{dt} = Kvs \frac{ds}{dt}$ to $\frac{dv}{v}  = k s ds$?

Also I want to know if an equation is being integrated, do we drop the constant of integration or it has to be included? For example, integration of this equation will yield

$\ln v = k s^2 /2$ or $\ln v + C_1 = \frac{k s^2}{2} + C_2 ??$

Comment: I edited your post. Please ensure I did not change the meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the integration constant is necessary to be included as it is that part of the formula, which will capture the info on the initial conditions. However, a single constant of integration is enough. So 
$$\ln v=k\frac{s^2}{2}+c$$
would do.

to compute the constant of integration you need info on the initial conditions: for example what would the value of $v$ be when $s=0$ or more generally when $s=s_0$.